# Firebase Realtime Database not connecting after disconnecting and then restarting an Internet connection

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app, at a certain point on clicking a button, the app needs to perform an operation on the RTDB (specifically, check the existence of a node). To ensure that the user is warned if they are not connected to a network, I am checking for that like so

```kotlin
private fun checkNet(): Boolean {
        val cm = context?.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val netC = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.activeNetwork)
        return (
                netC != null &&
                netC.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) &&
                netC.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED) &&
                (netC.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) ||
                        netC.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI ) ) 
                )
}
```

and then calling the function when necessary.

But the problem I am facing is that if the internet connection is lost and then regained, then even upon attaching a listener, it doesn't connect to the server. I realise that it takes time but the listener attached to the `.info/connected` location never fires when it is attached so

```kotlin
override fun onStop() {
     super.onStop()
     Firebase.database.getReference(".info/connected").removeEventListener(listener)
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    Firebase.database.getReference(".info/connected").addValueEventListener(listener)
}

object listener: ValueEventListener {
    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) = Unit
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val isCon = if (snapshot.value != null) snapshot.value as Boolean
                    else false
        if (isCon) Log.d(TAG, "connected".err())
        else Log.d(TAG, "not connected".err())
    }

}
```

even after triggering `onStart()` by leaving the app and returning to it, the listener doesn't log `connected`. It only connects when I close the entire app and then reopen it.

So, my question is that am I assuming the correct behaviour of `.info/connected`, and if so then what can I do to make sure that it connects to the RTDB after a reasonable amount of time in the presence of an internet connection ?

**Edit** - As @FrankVanPuffelen had suggested, I went ahead and enabled debug logging. After navigating to the fragment and accessing the database in the presence of an internet connection, the log output was

```
2020-07-03 15:58:50.167 com.example.paylater D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Listening on sellers/2 (params: {})
2020-07-03 15:58:50.167 com.example.paylater D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Adding listen query: sellers/2 (params: {})
2020-07-03 15:58:50.167 com.example.paylater D/Connection: conn_0 - Sending data: {t=d, d={a=q, r=20, b={p=sellers/2, h=}}}
2020-07-03 15:58:50.167 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 41278
2020-07-03 15:58:50.588 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_0 - ws message: {"t":"d","d":{"r":20,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{}}}}
2020-07-03 15:58:50.589 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44578
2020-07-03 15:58:50.589 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_0 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
2020-07-03 15:58:50.590 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_0 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {t=d, d={r=20, b={d={}, s=ok}}}
2020-07-03 15:58:50.590 com.example.paylater D/Connection: conn_0 - received data message: {r=20, b={d={}, s=ok}}
2020-07-03 15:58:50.591 com.example.paylater D/EventRaiser: Raising 1 event(s)
2020-07-03 15:58:50.591 com.example.paylater D/EventRaiser: Raising /sellers/2: VALUE: null
2020-07-03 15:58:50.620 com.example.paylater D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - unlistening on sellers/2 (params: {})
2020-07-03 15:58:50.620 com.example.paylater D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - removing query sellers/2 (params: {})
2020-07-03 15:58:50.620 com.example.paylater D/Connection: conn_0 - Sending data: {t=d, d={a=n, r=21, b={p=sellers/2}}}
2020-07-03 15:58:50.621 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44968
2020-07-03 15:58:51.228 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_0 - ws message: {"t":"d","d":{"r":21,"b":{"s":"ok","d":""}}}
2020-07-03 15:58:51.228 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44392
2020-07-03 15:58:51.228 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_0 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
2020-07-03 15:58:51.229 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_0 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {t=d, d={r=21, b={d=, s=ok}}}
2020-07-03 15:58:51.229 com.example.paylater D/Connection: conn_0 - received data message: {r=21, b={d=, s=ok}}
```

After disabling mobile data for 30s, then enabling it and accessing the RTDB again, the output was

```
2020-07-03 15:59:30.260 com.example.paylater D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Listening on sellers/2 (params: {})
2020-07-03 15:59:30.261 com.example.paylater D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Adding listen query: sellers/2 (params: {})
2020-07-03 15:59:30.262 com.example.paylater D/Connection: conn_0 - Sending data: {t=d, d={a=q, r=22, b={p=sellers/2, h=}}}
2020-07-03 15:59:30.263 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 5965
2020-07-03 16:00:15.263 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 0
2020-07-03 16:00:51.226 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_0 - WebSocket reached EOF.
2020-07-03 16:00:51.226 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_0 - closing itself
2020-07-03 16:00:51.226 com.example.paylater D/Connection: conn_0 - Realtime connection lost
2020-07-03 16:00:51.226 com.example.paylater D/Connection: conn_0 - closing realtime connection
2020-07-03 16:00:51.226 com.example.paylater D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Got on disconnect due to OTHER
2020-07-03 16:00:51.226 com.example.paylater D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
2020-07-03 16:00:51.226 com.example.paylater D/ConnectionRetryHelper: Scheduling retry in 0ms
2020-07-03 16:00:51.227 com.example.paylater D/EventRaiser: Raising 1 event(s)
2020-07-03 16:00:51.227 com.example.paylater D/EventRaiser: Raising /.info/connected: VALUE: false
2020-07-03 16:00:51.227 com.example.paylater D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
2020-07-03 16:00:51.229 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_0 - WebSocket error.
    com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocketException: IO Exception
        at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocketWriter.runWriter(WebSocketWriter.java:159)
        at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocketWriter.access$000(WebSocketWriter.java:30)
        at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocketWriter$1.run(WebSocketWriter.java:47)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.AbstractConscryptSocket.checkOpen(AbstractConscryptSocket.java:581)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket$SSLOutputStream.write(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:609)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Channels.java:453)
        at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocketWriter.writeMessage(WebSocketWriter.java:138)
        at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocketWriter.runWriter(WebSocketWriter.java:152)
        at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocketWriter.access$000(WebSocketWriter.java:30) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocketWriter$1.run(WebSocketWriter.java:47) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
2020-07-03 16:00:51.229 com.example.paylater D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Successfully fetched token, opening connection
2020-07-03 16:00:51.230 com.example.paylater D/Connection: conn_1 - Opening a connection
2020-07-03 16:00:51.233 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_0 - closed
2020-07-03 16:00:52.825 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - websocket opened
2020-07-03 16:00:52.825 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive
2020-07-03 16:00:52.826 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - ws message: {"t":"c","d":{"t":"h","d":{"ts":1593772513254,"v":"5","h":"s-usc1c-nss-203.firebaseio.com","s":"QMthzsHOAtBUR6Q05YGUpSKLJIeW1z6J"}}}
2020-07-03 16:00:52.826 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44998
2020-07-03 16:00:52.826 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
2020-07-03 16:00:52.827 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {t=c, d={t=h, d={h=s-usc1c-nss-203.firebaseio.com, s=QMthzsHOAtBUR6Q05YGUpSKLJIeW1z6J, v=5, ts=1593772513254}}}
2020-07-03 16:00:52.827 com.example.paylater D/Connection: conn_1 - Got control message: {t=h, d={h=s-usc1c-nss-203.firebaseio.com, s=QMthzsHOAtBUR6Q05YGUpSKLJIeW1z6J, v=5, ts=1593772513254}}
2020-07-03 16:00:52.827 com.example.paylater D/Connection: conn_1 - realtime connection established
2020-07-03 16:00:52.827 com.example.paylater D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - onReady
2020-07-03 16:00:52.827 com.example.paylater D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - handling timestamp
2020-07-03 16:00:52.827 com.example.paylater D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - calling restore state
2020-07-03 16:00:52.827 com.example.paylater D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Restoring auth.
2020-07-03 16:00:52.827 com.example.paylater D/Connection: conn_1 - Sending data (contents hidden)
2020-07-03 16:00:52.827 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44998
2020-07-03 16:00:52.828 com.example.paylater D/EventRaiser: Raising 1 event(s)
2020-07-03 16:00:52.829 com.example.paylater D/EventRaiser: Raising /.info/connected: VALUE: true
2020-07-03 16:00:53.466 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - ws message: {"t":"d","d":{"r":23,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{"auth":{"name":"Yash Singh","email_verified":false,"provider":"password","email":"yashsingh.real@gmail.com","user_id":"QBO65tn5qLVN8zyVB2uMA8UByJ02","token":{"name":"Yash Singh","email_verified":false,"email":"yashsingh.real@gmail.com","exp":1593775621,"user_id":"QBO65tn5qLVN8zyVB2uMA8UByJ02","iat":1593772021,"sub":"QBO65tn5qLVN8zyVB2uMA8UByJ02","aud":"the-creditinator","auth_time":1592475916,"iss":"https://securetoken.google.com/the-creditinator","firebase":{"identities":{"email":["yashsingh.real@gmail.com"]},"sign_in_provider":"password"}},"uid":"QBO65tn5qLVN8zyVB2uMA8UByJ02"},"expires":1593775621}}}}
2020-07-03 16:00:53.467 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44360
2020-07-03 16:00:53.467 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
2020-07-03 16:00:53.467 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {t=d, d={r=23, b={d={auth={uid=QBO65tn5qLVN8zyVB2uMA8UByJ02, email_verified=false, provider=password, user_id=QBO65tn5qLVN8zyVB2uMA8UByJ02, name=Yash Singh, email=yashsingh.real@gmail.com, token={sub=QBO65tn5qLVN8zyVB2uMA8UByJ02, aud=the-creditinator, email_verified=false, user_id=QBO65tn5qLVN8zyVB2uMA8UByJ02, auth_time=1592475916, name=Yash Singh, iss=https://securetoken.google.com/the-creditinator, exp=1593775621, firebase={sign_in_provider=password, identities={email=[yashsingh.real@gmail.com]}}, iat=1593772021, email=yashsingh.real@gmail.com}}, expires=1593775621}, s=ok}}}
2020-07-03 16:00:53.468 com.example.paylater D/Connection: conn_1 - received data message: {r=23, b={d={auth={uid=QBO65tn5qLVN8zyVB2uMA8UByJ02, email_verified=false, provider=password, user_id=QBO65tn5qLVN8zyVB2uMA8UByJ02, name=Yash Singh, email=yashsingh.real@gmail.com, token={sub=QBO65tn5qLVN8zyVB2uMA8UByJ02, aud=the-creditinator, email_verified=false, user_id=QBO65tn5qLVN8zyVB2uMA8UByJ02, auth_time=1592475916, name=Yash Singh, iss=https://securetoken.google.com/the-creditinator, exp=1593775621, firebase={sign_in_provider=password, identities={email=[yashsingh.real@gmail.com]}}, iat=1593772021, email=yashsingh.real@gmail.com}}, expires=1593775621}, s=ok}}
2020-07-03 16:00:53.468 com.example.paylater D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Restoring outstanding listens
2020-07-03 16:00:53.468 com.example.paylater D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Restoring listen sellers/2 (params: {})
2020-07-03 16:00:53.468 com.example.paylater D/Connection: conn_1 - Sending data: {t=d, d={a=q, r=24, b={p=sellers/2, h=}}}
2020-07-03 16:00:53.469 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44997
2020-07-03 16:00:53.471 com.example.paylater D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Restoring writes.
2020-07-03 16:00:54.105 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - ws message: {"t":"d","d":{"r":24,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{}}}}
2020-07-03 16:00:54.105 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44364
2020-07-03 16:00:54.106 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
2020-07-03 16:00:54.106 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {t=d, d={r=24, b={d={}, s=ok}}}
2020-07-03 16:00:54.106 com.example.paylater D/Connection: conn_1 - received data message: {r=24, b={d={}, s=ok}}
2020-07-03 16:00:54.106 com.example.paylater D/EventRaiser: Raising 1 event(s)
2020-07-03 16:00:54.107 com.example.paylater D/EventRaiser: Raising /sellers/2: VALUE: null
2020-07-03 16:00:54.107 com.example.paylater D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - unlistening on sellers/2 (params: {})
2020-07-03 16:00:54.107 com.example.paylater D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - removing query sellers/2 (params: {})
2020-07-03 16:00:54.108 com.example.paylater D/Connection: conn_1 - Sending data: {t=d, d={a=n, r=25, b={p=sellers/2}}}
2020-07-03 16:00:54.108 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44997
2020-07-03 16:00:54.632 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - ws message: {"t":"d","d":{"r":25,"b":{"s":"ok","d":""}}}
2020-07-03 16:00:54.633 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44474
2020-07-03 16:00:54.633 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
2020-07-03 16:00:54.633 com.example.paylater D/WebSocket: ws_1 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {t=d, d={r=25, b={d=, s=ok}}}
2020-07-03 16:00:54.633 com.example.paylater D/Connection: conn_1 - received data message: {r=25, b={d=, s=ok}}
```

After all this, it had given an output after roughly a minute, but the behaviour was not consistent and I hope the log messages can provide some insight into that.

Comment: The Firebase client tries to connect to server with an exponential back-off, so depending on how long you were without a connection it may take some time before it reconnects? How long did you wait for it to reconnect? It's probably also helpful to [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and check/include the output of that.

Comment: @FrankVanPuffelen I think I waited approx. half a minute before reconnecting. So is that enough to lead to a large amount of time before it reconnects, as I waited about 10 min. after turning on mobile data? Also, I'll go ahead and enable debug logging and include it's output as it seems it might lead to some insight.

Comment: Yeah, on a 30s disconnect it should definitely reconnect faster than what you say. Hopefully the debug logs provide some insight, as they show exactly when the client it trying to (re)connect and what response it got (if anything).